# Solar "side tap" configuration

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, solar

I am finalizing my configuration for a solar upgrade, and want to do a sanity check.

Jurisdiction: US, NY

The service is 200A, which routes to the meter and then to the main panel in the house.  Off that run is a 200A tap, which goes to a second service entrance, which is a 200A PV-combiner panel box.

Coming into the 200A PV-combiner panel box are existing inverters: a 7000W, a 4000W and a 3500W inverter.  I am adding four 7000W inverters.

It appears that the peak power output of the PV-combiner panel box would be 177A at 240VAC.  My nominal voltage at the PV-combiner is 253VAC.

The main panel box in the house is grounded via two rods and a loop of 6ga copper.  The PV-combiner box taps off L1, L2 and N, which run from the meter box to the main panel box.  The PV-combiner panel box has double ground rods with a 6ga Cu loop.

Heat pumps, compressors and various house loads total up to about a 100A max draw.
Given my high (177A peak output) I decided to upside my Cu wire from the tap to 3/0.

The service meter is outside the garage, along with a junction box with the tap to the PV-combiner, which is just inside the garage.  Original 4/0 Al runs from the transformer pad to the main panel box in the house.  The transformer is a nominal 48kW pad mounted transformer.

Am I overlooking anything?  It appears that the 120% rule does not apply because I have separate boxes for the house mains and for the PV-combiner. Any other considerations or concerns?

Comment: Does the main panel box for the house have a main breaker of its own?  Where is your 125% derate, are you using panels and equipment rated for 200A *continuous*? (continuous rated equipment is rather more expensive). Do you have a municipal requirement to use Cu wire and are you aware it will be attaching to lugs which are made of aluminum?

Comment: The main (house) panel has a 200A breaker.  The PV-combiner panel box has it's own 200A breaker.  I could not find anything relative to the PV-combiner panel box (Siemens 200A panel box) which qualified it for continuous or otherwise.  There is no municipal requirement to use Cu.  I have chosen to do so for the output of the PV-combiner because of the potential to thermal cycle daily.  Cu handles the cycling better than Al from a metallurgical standpoint, but I find no requirement for that. The Cu wire will be attaching to lugs rated for Cu or Al, or clad.

Comment: I do not think that the 125% derate applies, as there are no loads on the PV-combiner busbar, except the grid-connected side (panel box main breaker).

Comment: That’s… a lot of solar. Have you talked to your utility about updating your interconnection agreement for the new system size?

Comment: Are you saying PV panels are *not a load* and are thus exempt from 125%?  I don't think so... even so it bears on feeders (215.3, 220.87 after 1 year's data), and of course all of Article 690, including (in NEC 2014) 690.8(A)(3) and 690.9(B).   **What are the continuous output current ratings on each of the inverters?** This data is on the inverter nameplate and is not derived based on panel wattage.

Comment: It is allot of solar, and I have approval from the utility to proceed with the upgrade.

Comment: Perhaps I will get enlightened.  This is what I rely upon: Where two sources, one a utility and the other an inverter, are located at opposite ends of a busbar that contains loads, the sum of 125% of the inverter(s) output circuit current and the rating of the overcurrent device protecting the busbar shall not exceed 120% of the ampacity of the busbar.   Since there are only inverters and the grid connection on the PV-combiner, and NO LOADS, it appears that that the 120/125 rule does not apply.  If not, kindly explain (or provide an answer).

Comment: You don't have solar backfeeding the same bus that your utility feeds, so that 120/125 rule probably doesn't apply. But there's still the general "can't exceed 80% of part rating for continuous flows" rule. 177A (if accurate) going through a 200A combiner panel is 88.5%. You probably need to upgrade the combiner to a 225A unit (bus & breaker) if your inverters can really supply 177A. 177/225 is just  under 79%.

Comment: OK, so there is potentially a different spin on the max output.  The PV panels are on a barn roof, which is never really optimal, and will likely not output the nameplate 29A @240VAC.  Plus my nominal line voltage is 253 VAC over 97% of the time, so that will also reduce the current output.  It turns out that the bus on the panel I have is a 225A bus, but the main breaker is 200A, or so I am told.  I will try to verify. Things are never simple.

Comment: You have to do the load calculations based on nameplate amperage.

Comment: OK, I have another idea.  Replace the 200A breaker on the PV-combiner with a 150A breaker.  The insolation on the inverters for panels at one angle will be different than for the inverters at the second angle.  The 150A breaker assures that the bus can never continuously exceed 80%.

Comment: @mongo on the 120% rule, you've got that right IMO. The "125% of the inverter's output circuit current" is also correct.  But that does not mean if you clear the 120% issue that everything else is just automatically approved.

Comment: If you have separate panel strings that don’t get sun at exactly the same time, have you considered connecting them to one inverter? Could save you a few thousand bucks and drop your nameplate power total.

Comment: "another idea/200/150 breaker" *that's not how that works*.  This is a high-dollar project, and you are happy to throw cubic dollar at it *clearly*.  So why does this seem so "amateur hour"?  The cost of a pro to review this would be *rounding error* on total project cost. And save you a lot of entitlement headaches, when the inspector comes knocking.

Comment: Indeed… this must be around $50K worth of panels and $10K of inverters, plus all the ancillary parts and installation effort. Getting installation plans drawn up by a professional would probably be worthwhile for the sake of getting it done right the first time. Although finding one who’s not already booked solid for the next year (like seemingly all the trades right now) might be tricky.

Comment: I am seeking technical/code information, as opposed to financial review.  Trained professionals are in short supply, as are materials.  I appreciate to some people the idea of creatively looking for solutions might be less desirable than simply tearing out the existing PV-combiner and upgrading, if I can meet safety and operational requirements in economic ways, I am interested in doing so.  Indeed, the quotes I have are $89k, 93k and 99k.  My cost for panels, inverters, racking and wiring is under $34k. The 225A panel I ordered will be 2 mos out, and would require a new transformer and feeder

Comment: Did your utility say you’d need a new transformer and feeder if you use a 225A combiner or are you assuming? Utilities play by their own special rules, not the NEC.

Comment: If you could provide more detail (nameplate data of all service and generation equipment you have and plan to install), plus a schematic of how you plan to hook it all up, you may get more specific responses.

Comment: @nobody, the utility had previously called for a transformer upgrade.  I questioned it but they insisted. After I agreed to pay for the upgrade, the pre-construction site visit confirmed my finding, and they backed down on the upgrade.  Changing to a 225A service would require a transformer upgrade, new service feed and trenching.  The site is 650 feet from the pole at the road.

Comment: Wait, with that distance you need to step-up for transmission *anyway*...  or use insane cable (1000 Kcmil Al? Still cheaper than 3/0Cu lol ). Two 240/480 transformers back to back etc.

Comment: Apparent solution in hand.  Inspector came today, and aside from comment that the job is the neatest he has seen in solar, we went over the 125% rule.  I had a worksheet showing that the code guidance was 337.5A for my configuration.  Also had a worksheet showing that the highest anticipated generation was 99.7 A.  He said he was good with that and issued the certificate.